# do IBAction on shake gesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ibaction

I have set my iPhone app up so that it writes "Shake!" to the `NSLog` when the user shakes the iPhone:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
NSLog(@"shake!");
}
}
```

and this is working. I have got an IBAction in my code as well. Can I set it to do the IBAction when it is shaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call any method you like, but if the method declaration you have set as an IBAction contains a sender then you will need to send nil as the parameter....

```
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender
```

Then you can call...

```
[self doSomething:nil];
```